# font-family in webview (react native - ios)

Tags: css, ios, react-native

I have a weird issued when setting the font-family in a css styleSheet to render html in a WebView.
I imported 2 fonts in xcode (Arial Rounded MT Bold and Arial Rounded MT). Those fonts work perfectly in Text components, but in WebView, only Arial Rounded MT Bold works. I use this to set the font:

```
const styleSheet = `* {
          font-family: "Arial Rounded MT Bold";
          font-size: 11px;
          color: ${appColors.textGrey};
      }`
```

Any idea how to make Arial Rounded MT work?

Comment: Add the fonts to the `Info.plist` and the fonts must also be the family name as printed in iOS when you print `UIFont.familyName`

Comment: I've done that. As I wrote, the fonts work in native components, it's only Arial Rounded MT that is not applied in a webView.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer, it's dead simple.
It works when I write it like this:

```
font-family: 'Arial Rounded MT', Arial, sans-serif;
```